Is there a "simple" way to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS (in-place)?
I have many small Ubuntu devices at remote locations running on 18.04 LTS, used as VPN-Gateway only. All of them have an activated PRO subscription, thus receive all updates.
Configured are:

2 interfaces with /etc/network/interfaces.d/{eth0,eth1} (not netplan!)
openvpn with one connection (certificate based)
simple openvpn watchdog script running from cron.hourly
dnsmasq (DNS and DHCP for eth1)
netbird agent as second ways to connect
zabbix agent

Is it possible/feasible to do an in-place upgrade?
If yes, how would I proceed best?
In-place upgrade is preferred. Otherwise I have to prepare exchange devices for each remote site.
(limited Ubuntu knowledge here...)

Ubuntu Core 18 is a snap only version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server; you mention Core & 18.04 which are different products.  I suggest checking your details & clarifying what you're asking.

This question is similar to: Can I skip over releases when upgrading?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

corrected text. Linux knowledge limited here. I was told by the engineer that the installed version is Ubuntu core...

Then check, as if you upgrade a Ubuntu Core 18 system to later releases, the user-apps do not need upgrading making the upgrade easier... This does not apply to a 18.04 system, where almost all deb packages will get upgraded on upgrade (ie. system + user applications will be upgraded)..  Ubuntu Core is a different system to the standard year.month products...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades provides clues as to the 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade; though of course release notes should also be read (issues & mitigation details are mostly in release notes)... Once on 20.04 (focal), you can then explore the next upgrade which is to 22.04 or jammy using the JammyUpgrades doc & release notes... etc... That is the in-place upgrade option, otherwise it's a re-install process

This question is similar to: How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1521122/289138

I am confused. The comments vaguely seem to claim Ubuntu Core 18, but the Question text and tags say Ubuntu 18.04. Big difference Please edit your question to be completely clear about exactly what is running on this system. Use proper names. Else you will get wrong answers that will break your systems.
